# there exists a diagonalizable linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Proof or disprove the following :

There exists a diagonalizable linear transformation $T: \mathbb{C}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{2}$ with eigenvalues$\pm i$

Any help or hint is appreciated

Comment: $T = \begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: But that´s just a matrix ... what would be the explicit linear tranformation ?

Comment: @user132226 $T(x,y)=(ix,-iy)$.

Comment: Well, take the linear transformation $x \mapsto Tx$.

Comment: @copper.hat might as well make that an answer, I think

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Took your suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the transformation $L(x) = Tx$, where
$T = \begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be the vector space  of all complex-valued  functions of the form 
$a\sin z + b\cos z$ with $a,b$ complex numbers. This is a 2-dimensional complex vector space. Define $T\colon V\to V$ to be the linear transformation $\frac{d}{dz}$. Ths has $\pm i$ as its eigenvalues.